# Playwright - error is thrown - iframe appears to be hidden

Tags: javascript, playwright

selector resolved to hidden <iframe scrolling="no" id="checkframe" name="checkframe"…>

I am getting the above error when searching for frame. Can someone help me get around this please.

This is the code I have written

```
async waitForCheckPageToLoad(){
        let checkFrame = this.page.frameLocator('#checkframe');
        let button = checkframe.locator('div[class="CondButton"]');
        await button.waitFor({timeout: 15000});
}
```

Comment: Can you share the site and a [mcve] please? It's hard to help without it.

Comment: Not having much information as details are not provided. Frame locators won't work if more than one frame is found(I know Id is provided but it can be repeated in a page by any function), https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-framelocator [check strictness action]